# Building a livestream page where the user will input an rtsp streaming source through an ip address

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtsp

I am building a livestream page where the streaming source is streamed through rtsp. Currently, I am using ffmpeg to convert the incoming rtsp stream to a .m3u8 file  and it is played back on the webpage through HLS.

The problem i am trying to solve now, is loading an rtsp stream based on the user's input. How do i go about solving this?  It is a requirement to able to view the stream on iOS and android.
The ffmpeg command :

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://10.193.79.185:5554" -hls_time 3 -hls_wrap 10 "C:\wamp64\www\hls\output.m3u8"
```

Code of what I have at the moment that loads a hard coded rtsp stream

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
      <center>
          <h1>RTSP Stream</h1>
                <input  type ="text" name="rtspAddress" placeholder="RTSP address">
                <input  type ="text" name="output" placeholder="output Name">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Start</button>
                <video height="600" id="video" controls></video>
      </center>
      

      <script>
        if(Hls.isSupported()) 
        {
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var mystring = "http://192.168.43.79/hls/output.m3u8";
            var hls = new Hls({
              debug: true
            });
            hls.loadSource(mystring);
            hls.attachMedia(video);
            hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function() {
            video.muted = true;
            video.play();
        });
        }
        // hls.js is not supported on platforms that do not have Media Source Extensions (MSE) enabled.
        // When the browser has built-in HLS support (check using `canPlayType`), we can provide an HLS manifest (i.e. .m3u8 URL) directly to the video element throught the `src` property.
        // This is using the built-in support of the plain video element, without using hls.js.
        else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
            video.src = 'http://192.168.43.79/hls/output.m3u8';
            video.addEventListener('canplay',function() {
            video.play();
          });
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need some script on the backend that starts/runs FFmpeg. E.g. you can build a php script with the [exec command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) that runs FFmpeg.

To send the user input to this php script you can follow [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). Basically you need a `form` with an input field in the HTML and send a request to your php script (`action` attribute). In php you can access to the user input via `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables.